# moustache variable does not expand in class or id tag

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I want to make an id and/or class tag in the html template of a vue component expandable with a variable. I googled but haven't found specifically making id or class tags.

Most of my tests boil down to this:

```html
    <script setup>
    defineProps( {
      ids: {
        type: Number
      }
    })
    </script>
    <script>
    export default {
      name: "simple-component",
      nom: 1,
      data() {
        return {
          id: 1
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
    
    <template>
      <div>{{ id }}</div>
     <div id="{{ ids }}" v-once class="Control-Template{{ id }}">
```

So here I have tried 2 main thoughts on how to use it. The Property is set in the main.vue using the component to a number. The div with only id is for verifying that the id is set.
If I use

```html
    <Component ids="3"/>
```

in main.vue and want to write out the value in the test-div it does not even work. It only works with the export id. nom is not working as well in id or class tags.
v-link does not work either this way of using it.

So how can I make a class/id name for my div defined with a variable?
It is supposed to make my controls identifyable to update the content data from push data.

So my use-case is having the same component many times in main.vue and each instance gets different data to be displayed from the server.

Comment: @bassxzero thanks for the link but I thought I did it that way. I will give it another try and get back to you if it does solve the problem.

Comment: `defineProps()` returns a ref that you need to assign to a variable so that the `<script setup>` will expose it to your html template.

Comment: @bassxzero I see what you mean in the linked question. How come that this is not necessary for the HelloWorld example that gets created from create-vue? There is a msg tag that just gets set and it works? I was copying the methodology from there.

Comment: Actually idk. I think @A.Z is correct actually.

Comment: @bassxzero He is. Maybe the Hot Update didn't work when I tried it until I redid it now that way and restarted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do `data binding` between your data and html.

Vue handles it following way

Make use of `key` bindings provided by vue for ref check [key binding](https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/syntax.html#v-bind-Shorthand)

Your code will look as following

```html
<script setup>
defineProps( {
  ids: {
    type: Number
  }
})
</script>
<script>
export default {
  name: "simple-component",
  nom: 1,
  data() {
    return {
      id: 1
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <div>{{ id }}</div>
  <div :id="ids" v-once :class="'Control-Template'+id"></div>
</template>
```

Check out [sfc playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNpVUc1ugzAMfhXLl7ZaAe0asUrT7tMOO+aSgrulIj9KDNuEePcZKJV682fH348z4muM5dATKqxzk2xkyMR9PGnf0sV6+kgh5j2M2gPYNqu1AuC/SAree3emNHcm7aeD9nW1ssj+jU8q+o0hMQih6TteGbxxsq8xWxc7KprgYvDkWeNxGQen4HkpW8Nmf9h0k7hLfkOzJ3m3ArGw+niwIYBJNAyTIIC6tcNpHGURpqmuZrS1Qdn2RaPE1AhDEXxDoJrO5Czd3VvwnEJXfN7Ydk+21XjaKOrqLoNHlFQSuXAmltccvJx3cSzky0AE7pfUKPefscZv5phVVeVLM3/KNZchfVVSlan3bB2VlF1xTuEnUxJijVtknP4BasGa/Q==) for working example.

Comment: I actually tried this but it first didn't work. Don't know why it does not work. Just one thing I found was that I have to define type string instead of number or I get a vue warning.